# interactive graph with matplotlib and networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

My probelm is the following:

I want to draw a graph with networkx and matplotlib. While showing the graph my programm is supposed to process some other stuff. So I came up with the `matplotlib.pyplot.ion()`function to allow the interactive mode.

My code:

```
def print_graph(graph):
    """ prints the graph"""

    # stores the nodes and their name attributes in a dictionary
    nodes_names = nx.get_node_attributes(graph, "name")
    plt.ion()
    pos = nx.spring_layout(graph)

    # draw without labels, cuz it would label them with their adress, since we
    nx.draw(graph, pos, with_labels=False)

    # draw the label with the nodes_names containing the name attribute
    labels = nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph, pos, nodes_names)
    plt.show()

def setup_sending(graph, iteration):
"""method which handles sending messages in the network,
only call it once for sending sweet packages in a network"""
    print_graph(graph)

    ###some code doing calculations....

    raw_input('Press enter to continue')
```

running this does not really work. Wll, it does all the calculations and even opens a figure-window. But this window which should show the graph is processing something and remains white. Of coures after pressing Enter I exit the programm.

So does anyone have an idea how to make the code show the graph?

---

**EDIT**

```
 def setup_graph(laplacian):
""" this fucntion creates a graph object with the nodes and its edges
already correct initialized"""
    # this block adds the nodes to the graph and creates two dict
    # in order to label the graph correctly
    size = len(laplacian[0, :])
    my_graph = nx.Graph()
    for i in range(size):
        my_graph.add_node(Node(), name=str(i + 1))
    print(my_graph.nodes())
    # stores the nodes and their name attributes in a dictionary
    nodes_names = nx.get_node_attributes(my_graph, "name")
    # switches key and values--> thus names_nodes
    names_nodes = dict(zip(nodes_names.values(), nodes_names.keys()))

    # this block adds the edges between the nodes
    for i in range(0, size):
        for j in range(i + 1, size):
            if laplacian[i, j] == -1:
                node_1 = names_nodes[str(i + 1)]
                node_2 = names_nodes[str(j + 1)]
                my_graph.add_edge(node_1, node_2)

    return my_graph
```

`Node()` is just a object containing certain lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def print_graph(graph):
    """ prints the graph"""

    # stores the nodes and their name attributes in a dictionary
    nodes_names = nx.get_node_attributes(graph, "name")
    plt.ion()
    pos = nx.spring_layout(graph)

    # draw without labels, cuz it would label them with their adress, since we
    nx.draw(graph, pos, with_labels=False)

    # draw the label with the nodes_names containing the name attribute
    labels = nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph, pos, nodes_names)
    plt.show()

def setup_sending(graph):
    print_graph(graph)

    ###some code doing calculations....

    raw_input('Press enter to continue')

def main():
    G=nx.dodecahedral_graph()
    setup_sending(G)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

so, I think your problem could be the size of your graph. How large is it? How many nodes/edges does it have?

Comment: It has 6 nodes. So it is not too large.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the part of code where you add edges is not right. You've been trying to add edges by their names, not by object. So, assuming to have two nodes: (a, name="foo") and (b, name="bar"). If you add an edge between "foo" and "bar", then you are not connecting "a" and "b", but other two NEW nodes named "foo" and "bar". I think the best thing is to add getter method inside your Node() object. To be sure this is the real issue, what happens if you print your graph inside the `print_graph(graph)` method? I mean, try and put something like this: `print str(graph.edges())`

Comment: comparing the output of `print(my_graph.nodes())` and `print(my_graph.edges())`it seems like the  node objects are the correct ones. However I am not a 100% sure, since I do not have much experience in python. But as far as I understand the assignment `node_1 = names_nodes[str(i + 1)]` retrieves the Node-object from the dictionary and just makes node_1 point to the same Node-object.

Comment: So, `print str(graph.edges())` in `print_graph(graph)` outputs the correct graph, right? If yes, please paste here your output.

Comment: [<__main__.Node object at 0x05EB1030>, <__main__.Node object at 0x05EB1050>, <__main__.Node object at 0x05EB1070>, <__main__.Node object at 0x05EB1090>, <__main__.Node object at 0x05EB10B0>, <__main__.Node object at 0x05EB10D0>]

Comment: [(<__main__.Node object at 0x05EB1030>, <__main__.Node object at 0x05EB10B0>), (<__main__.Node object at 0x05EB1030>, <__main__.Node object at 0x05EB1050>), (<__main__.Node object at 0x05EB1050>, <__main__.Node object at 0x05EB10B0>), (<__main__.Node object at 0x05EB1050>, <__main__.Node object at 0x05EB1070>), (<__main__.Node object at 0x05EB1070>, <__main__.Node object at 0x05EB1090>), (<__main__.Node object at 0x05EB1090>, <__main__.Node object at 0x05EB10B0>), (<__main__.Node object at 0x05EB1090>, <__main__.Node object at 0x05EB10D0>)]

Comment: i know it is ugly, but here you can see form the output of `graph.nodes()`and `graph.edges()` that they point to the same objects

Comment: Ok, at this point I think the best thing is to paste all your code in order to debug it.

Comment: this is basically the whole code. the other stuff is not related to this in any way.. however i redesigned the structure of my programm in order to use the figures i create at the end. I split the calculation part from the part which generates the figures and animations. So it doesnt matter that i cant show the figures at runtime..

Comment: i really appreciate your efforts!